# Why does Ruby gsub not replace a second occurrence of this pattern?

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub, ruby-1.8.7

I have a bit of code for escaping double-quotes from a string which may include pre-escaped quotes; e.g:

```
This is a \"string"
```

Using the following code with Ruby 1.8.7p374:

```
string.gsub!(/([^\\])"/, '\1\"')
```

However, I get some funny edge-case when trying it on the following string: `ab""c` => `ab\""c`. I would expect it to have escaped both quotes.

It's definitely not a big issue, but it got me curious.
Is this a mistake with my expression? A `gsub` bug/feature?

(In newer Ruby versions, this could probably be solved easily by using negative lookbacks, but they seem to be not supported in this version).

Comment: The problem is overlapping expressions, the `([^\\])` is not going to match the `"` you have just replaced.

Comment: It is not clear what you have. If the `"` at the end is a double quote character, then that would be described escaped as `\"`. But then, the `\"` before that would mean you have a backslash character followed by a double quote character, which would be described as `\\\"` when escaped. Is this really what you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex also won’t work if there is a quote at the *start* of a string, e.g. `"ab""c` will transform to `"ab\""c`. The reason for this is similar to your case with double quotes.

After `gsub` has matched `b"` and replaced it, it continues from the last match, looking at the next `"`, but doesn’t look at the previously consumed characters.

You might be able to fix your issue with a lookbehind in newer Ruby versions, but that won’t fix the beginning of string problem. The way to fix that is to use the [`\G` anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) (which is available in Ruby 1.8.7), which matches where the previous match ended or at the start of the string. So you are looking for a `"` that is *either* immediately after an non slash *or* is at the start of the current match (meaning a `"` has just been matched or this is the start of the string). Something like this:

```
string.gsub!(/([^\\]|\G)"/, '\1\"')
```

This will convert the string `"ab""c` to `\"ab\"\"c`.

Answer (score 3):

Requiring a match to a non-`\` character means the regex needs to *consume* that character as well as the quote. The `gsub` matches also cannot overlap.

You are right that a look-behind assertion would fix this. But without that available, you have a couple of choices in Ruby 1.8.7.

1. Repeat until there are no substitutions made (`gsub!` returns `nil` if there were no matches):

   `loop { break unless string.gsub!(/([^\\])"/, '\1\"') }`
2. For 1.8.7, you don't have look-behind assertions. But you can reverse the string, use *look-ahead* assertions to make your changes, then reverse it back:

   `string = string.reverse.gsub(/"(?!\\)/, '"\\').reverse`